# Is it correct to say "The boy rolled the clay into a tube with his palms"?

Tags: phrase-usage

We can use our fingers to "**roll a big mat into a tube**".

However, clay is not flat so to make a tube out of clay, a boy puts the clay between his palms then he rubs his palms together and thus create a tube out of the clay.

Can we say "**The boy rolled the clay into a tube with his palms**"?

Or **do we have a verb for that action?**

Comment: A "tube" is a *hollow* cylinder. A boy cannot roll clay into a tube between the palms of his hands. There's no specific word for it, but I think most English speakers would call it a "snake". Replace "tube" with "snake" and your sentence is natural.

Comment: I'd call it a cylinder.

Comment: Incidentally, I would just say 'roll up a mat' - we know what shape a rolled mat is.

Comment: I think most people would understand it, and it's grammatical, even if you could quibble about whether it's a tube.

Comment: Tubes are not always hollow. A tube of toothpaste is not hollow. The headline sentence sounds fine.

Comment: Note that whenever you say palms, it's very common to say ... "with the palms of his hands".  Of course it's redundant, but that's the colloquial formulation.

Comment: @Fattie The toothpaste tube is the hollow container, which is then filled with paste.

Comment: @Fattie I'm also on team "go ahead and say tube" here, but a tube of toothpaste is absolutely hollow.

Comment: a "toothpaste tube" is a hollow thing you might see in a Colgate factory. in the bathroom a tube of toothpaste means the paste and the outside, the "whole thing"

Comment: @Fattie I'd say that's true in much the same way that a "bottle of milk" includes both the bottle and the milk, but a "milk bottle" would be just the bottle, whether or not it contains any milk.  One word refers to the container, while the other refers to its contents.  Together with the word "of" it means the whole thing.

Comment: Tom is actually asking about "rolled".  Tom, "rolled" is perfect. In some cases you may like "formed".

Comment: Note, "roll a big mat into a tube".  You would never call a roll of carpet, or a rolled mat, a "tube".  They're not tubes.

Comment: Tom - essentially, *every single thing in your question is wrong* - other than, the word "rolled" which you were asking about, that word is correct!  Heh! :)

Comment: I would expect the word "sausage" to be used. (Unless it is indeed a hollow tube, formed out of a flat sheet, but that would be exceptional.)

Comment: A "roll" is what you get when you "roll" a flexible substance like dough or clay, or roll up a flat substance like a rug or piece of paper.

Comment: @gotube you can't roll it into a tube, but you *can* roll it into a [snake](https://www.google.com/search?q=snake&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)?

Comment: @mcalex Yes, roll it into a snake, or as suggested above, a "sausage".

Comment: "We can use our fingers to "roll a big mat into a tube". Frankly, no. We can use our fingers to "roll up" the mat.

Comment: The boy rolled the clay into a **tube shape**. Snake? Not idiomatic here. The boy made a roll of the clay.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is actually a technical term, which would be appropriate if the boy was a potter, and not just playing. A cylindrical piece of clay rolled by hand is called a "[coil](https://thepotterywheel.com/how-to-roll-a-clay-coil/)" by potters, from its use in making coil pots.  You could talk about "rolling a (clay) coil". or "rolling out the clay into coils"

Otherwise a "sausage" or other metaphor works well.

Comment: While this is technically correct, and "tube" is technically incorrect, I don't really feel like this is usable outside of an audience that understands (or should be led to understand) the jargon.  If I'd read that phrase without this context, I'd be thinking, "What, like a spring?  Wow, the author is telling me he has impressive skill!"  Meanwhile with tube, while I'm perhaps unclear on whether the clay is loosely rolled to be hollow or squished solid, I clearly imagine the action that is being described.

Comment: I've mentioned, I hope clearly enough, that "coil" is what potters call this.  But something like "sausage" is better for regular humans.

Comment: Wait, what? You've all got a problem with 'tube' because it may or may not have to be hollow, and some people don't like cylinder because of irregularity, but no-one has issues with a sausage being a food made of pork?  Why can't tube be a metaphor?  I mean, try and find a definition of sausage that isn't along the lines of 'a *tube* or *cylinder* of (some type of) meat'. No issues with coil given its technical correctness (though outside of pottery circles a coil is what you make out of the tube when you wrap it around itself), but 'tube' is better than sausage for regular humans.

Comment: @mcalex the reason 'sausage' is better than 'cylinder' is that you _could_ conceivably have a cylinder of clay, or even a tube, just forming them with only one's hands would be quite challenging. Whereas saying 'sausage' leaves absolutely no doubt that it's meant as a metaphor, because it's physically impossible to transform the clay into actual meat. For your other point, describing a (meat) sausage as a tube _filled_ with meat is just literally correct, however it's not the meat that is the tube but instead the casing. Describing a sausage as a cylinder would be a rather weird.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I would always have said "sausage" (although in Scotland it might have to be "link"), but from now on I'll say "coil", and with an aloof expression on my face to indicate that I am using a technical term of art. Now all I have to do is find myself in a scenario where giving clay-rolling instructions is required.

Answer (score 15):

I also agree with "roll".  I think many native English speakers would colloquially say "tube" even if it's not hollow.  The part I find awkward is "palms".  Based on my experience, I think a native English speaker would almost certainly say "hands", and let palms be implicit. It's not incorrect; it just sounds unnatural to me.  Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCsL-Sewqqg) where you can see a woman discussing rolling out a clay coil. She never says she's using her palms, but rather her hands.

Comment: "Palms" is more specific than "hands". The boy could be using his fingers, and saying "palms" makes it clear that isn't the case.

Comment: Interestingly, saying the boy _rolled a clay cylinder between his palms_ sounds fine to me, but it discusses the rolling motion rather than the forming of the clay. Otherwise, using palms is certainly more specific but feels less natural. I think you only need to be more specific than "hands" if you're doing something unusual, such as if you're taking care to avoid the fingers, or don't have fingers in the first place.

Comment: This answer is exactly correct.

Comment: @Useless I agree that rolling something *between* your palms sounds natural.  It's "rolling something with your palms" that sounds unnatural unless there is a specific reason to be very specific justified by the context.

Comment: Have to disagree with you on this. "Palms" seems very natural to me as a native speaker, and I think it provides a clearer mental image than just saying "hands". I can't think of a context where using a vaguer word is beneficial.

Answer (score 6):

I would agree with "roll". it is "tube" I would dispute as the result of this action is (generally) not hollow.

I would likely call it a "strand", "rope" or even "snake".

Comment: *The boy rolled a clay snake.* - they still make play-doh, right?

Comment: Tubes are not hollow. Rope is braided string.  Snakes are animals.

Comment: @mcalex You are being unnecessarily literalist. "Tube" is ambiguous because a hollow tube is also a basic form clay can be shaped into. If "snake" meant a detailed rendering of the animal, that would certainly be stated, not to mention the first step in doing so would be the same as what is actually meant here.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you I agree with *your* words in principle, but that is not what everybody else is arguing.  The first comment to the question is 'A boy cannot roll clay into a tube between the palms of his hands'.  The general assumption seems to be that palm-rolled clay is solid.  My argument (to that assumption) is that if you can call it snake, or rope, then you can (and should) call it tube.  To your ambiguity argument, I say, OK technically, but when or for what purpose are you ever going to roll clay into a (hollow) tube form?   In the context of clay rolling, 'tube' is not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is fine, although "tube" may confuse users to show that there is a circle in the middle (hollow). I would call it a "coil" or "loop", which removes this ambiguity of being hollow. These two choices seems most natural to me.

loop:

> a shape produced by a curve that bends round and crosses itself. [Source](https://www.lexico.com/definition/loop)

Comment: How are you picturing the action? _Loop_ would imply a length of clay formed into a hoop or tire shape. _Coil_ makes me think of a long, thin rope-like piece of clay that is then wound circularly around a central gap — think coils of rope (edit: or a spiral shape). Neither of these could be produced by rolling between one's palms. I'm pretty sure Tom's intent is that the boy is forming a solid log or sausage shape.

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, the problem with your sentence is that the boy is not producing a "tube".

Rolling the clay into a "snake" is good if the result is long and thin like a snake, but since you're comparing it with a rolled-up mat, I don't think that works in your case.

I also wouldn't say "cylinder", because that is a specific shape with even width and flat ends, and saying that the boy created a cylinder seems to imply a more precise result than the longish blob that you're talking about.

How about "**The boy rolled the clay into a short length with his palms**?".  That reads quite well, I think.